# How do I reference "*args" in a discord bot's code as a message for the bot to send?

Tags: python, bots, discord

This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def repeat(*args):
    output = ''
    for word in args:
        output += str(word)
        output += " "
    await client.say(output)
```

`client.say(output)` does not work, but I tried to do it in this form:
`await message.channel.send(output)`
However, I don't know what to put for `message` as my function's parameter is `*args`
Is there a something else I can put as the `message`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to have a parameter for your command so that context can be passed to it, this is ctx in this case. `client.say()` is not what you want to use anymore. I've changed your code a bit, hopefully this helps.

```
@client.command()
async def repeat(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send(' '.join(args))
```